# autoResizeColumn() multiple columns google apps script without extra API calls

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, multiple-columns, autoresize

I am trying to autoresize multiple columns without extra API calls. I am currently doing this:

```
 for (var column = 6; column <= 105; column++) {
    targetSheet.autoResizeColumn(column);
  }
```

This is taking up too much execution time for me with all the extra API calls. I can do things like `dateRange = targetSheet.getRange(2,6,1,99);` and then `dateRange.getValues(); or dateRange.setValues();` all at once, but I can't seem to figure it out with `autoResizeColumn` because I can't call this function on a range.

Comment: I don't see any way around this; since a script can't resize multiple columns at once, you have to do it one by one.

Comment: ugh! You would think with how they preach "best practices" all over their support page that they would have better support for reducing calls to other services.